# Is it possible to get maven to accept maxerrs for its compiler plugin?

Tags: java, maven-2, javac

I have a project where I am responsible for fixing some errors and another developer is responsible for other errors.  The number of errors is well over a hundred, and as I'm fixing my errors, her errors are piling up.  I'm at the point where I see 99 of her errors and one of mine, and I assume I will soon get to a point where it is 100 of hers.  I looked into using this configuration for maven:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <compilerArgument>-Xmaxerrs 1000</compilerArgument>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But no dice:

```
Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
javac: invalid flag: -Xmaxerrs 1000
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

On the command line using javac, the maxerrs flag works as expected, but I can't seem to make the leap to maven with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the ["Map syntax"](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html) worked for me:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <fork>true</fork>
      <compilerArguments>
        <Xmaxerrs>1000</Xmaxerrs>
      </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

The option is passed as expected:

```
$ mvn clean compile -X
...
[DEBUG] Using compiler 'javac'.
[DEBUG] Source directories: [/home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3358242/src/main/java]
[DEBUG] Classpath: [/home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3358242/target/classes]
[DEBUG] Output directory: /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3358242/target/classes
[DEBUG] Classpath:
[DEBUG]  /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3358242/target/classes
[DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3358242/src/main/java
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3358242/target/classes -classpath /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3358242/target/classes: -sourcepath /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3358242/src/main/java: /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3358242/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/q3358242/App.java -g -nowarn -target 1.5 -source 1.5 -encoding UTF-8 -Xmaxerrs 1000
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3358242/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

The odd part is that I get the **exact same debug output** (with the **exact** same *Command line options*) when using the alternative configuration you provided... except that it fails due to a *Failure executing javac*. You should raise a [Jira issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER), there is definitely something weird.

Comment: @Pascal - is the *"alternative configuration"* you refer to the one in my answer?

Comment: @Stephen No, I'm referring to the configuration posted by the OP, which is IMO correct (I mean conform to the documentation).

Comment: @Stephen Just tested your suggestion (the one of your answer), only the last `compilerArgument` get passed (1000 here). I guess you're not supposed to pass several `compilerArgument`.

Comment: Confusingly `<compilerArgs><Xmaxerrs>1000</Xmaxerrs></compilerArgs>` doesn't work (at least with 3.2 plugin), but this does (also, `<fork>true</fork>` doesn't seem to be required)

Answer (score 1):

Updating answer for 2022. This works for me with `maven-compiler-plugin` version 3.8.1:

```xml
<configuration>
     <source>${compiler.source}</source>
     <target>${compiler.target}</target>
     <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
     <compilerArgs>
         <arg>-Xmaxerrs</arg>
         <arg>10000</arg>
     </compilerArgs>
 </configuration>
```