# Java 6: how to pass multiple parameters to APT

Tags: java, maven-2, annotations, javac, apt

I have a Java Annotation Processor that extends from [AbstractProcessor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html).

I have two supported options, `addResDir` and `verbose`, and I am trying to set them like this:

```
-AaddResDir=src/main/webapp -Averbose=true
```

I have also tried this:

```
-AaddResDir=src/main/webapp,verbose=true
```

While a single parameter works, e.g.

```
-AaddResDir=src/main/webapp
```

I can't get the multiple parameters to work and I can't find any relevant docs. Do I need to parse the parameters manually in APT?

The only thing I have is the output of `javac -help`:

```
-Akey[=value]   Options to pass to annotation processors
```

---

**EDIT**

It turns out to be a maven problem, after all. Here is my maven config:

```
<plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <optimize>true</optimize>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <compilerArgument>-AaddResDir=src/main/webapp -Averbose=true</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately, maven sends the argument to Javac as a single string in the args array, while it should of course be two Strings. The Map Version `<compilerAguments>` is no help either, because

```
<Averbose>true</Averbose>
<AaddResDir>src/main/webapp</AResDir>
```

generates the output:

```
[... , -Averbose, true, -AaddResDir, src/main/webapp]
```

While javac requires the syntax

```
[... , -Averbose=true, -AaddResDir=src/main/webapp ]
```

and

```
<Averbose=true />
<AaddResDir=src/main/webapp />
```

is invalid XML.

(See [Mapping Maps](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Maps) from the [Guide to Configuring Maven Plugins](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html))

And I am afraid there is no way to change this, argh.

---

**EDIT:**

I have now [filed a bug report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-135).

Comment: Actually, I think that your issue duplicates [MCOMPILER-130](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-130) which has been raised after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358242/is-it-possible-to-get-maven-to-accept-maxerrs-for-its-compiler-plugin. But the map syntax won't save you here indeed.

Comment: No I wouldn't say it's a dupe as the annotation params have a different syntax and there is no workaround for it.

Comment: I think you're actually right, the problem is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real answer as of yet.

The bug is filed: [MCOMPILER-135](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-135)

and I have submitted three different patches, [the last of which](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/attachment/51191/AbstractCompilerMojo.java.3.patch) introduces a variable of type [Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

```
<additionalCompilerArguments>
    <property> <name>-Akey=value</name> </property>
    <property> <name>-verbose</name> </property>
    <property> <name>-Xmaxerrs</name> <value>1000</value> </property>
</additionalCompilerArguments>
```

This solution is the most flexible one because it supports many different parameter syntax formats.

(If the existing parameter `<compilerArguments>` were also of type Properties my problem would be solved)