# Javac not running annotation processors

Tags: java, maven, code-generation, javac

### Problem

I'm revisiting a maven project that I haven't touched in at least a year. I'm pretty sure it was compiling successfully when I left it (there was still a working jar in the `target` directory), but now compilation fails because generated classes are missing.

### What I tried

- Verified there are indeed no sources in `target/generated-sources/annotations` (**none present**)
- Ensured javac wasn't invoked with `-proc:none` (**it wasn't**)
- Ran `mvn clean dependency:unpack-dependencies -Dmdep.useSubDirectoryPerArtifact=true` to ensure the expected dependencies are on the classpath and that they contain a valid `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` entry (**yes** there were multiple, including `org.immutables.processor.ProxyProcessor`
  )
- Followed these steps from [How to make sure javac is using an annotation processor and troubleshoot when it is not](http://www.javatronic.fr/articles/2014/08/31/how_to_make_sure_javac_is_using_a_specific_annotation_processor.html):

  1. Take the javac options from the maven debug log
  2. Remove `-nowarn` option and add `-verbose -XprintRounds -XprintProcessorInfo -Xlint -J-verbose`. NOTE: I also had to add the relative path to the main class, or javac would complain there are no sources.
  3. Verify if class of processor is loaded (**not present**)
  4. Look for at least one processing round log (**none present**)
  5. Make sure annotations are present in the list of the round log (**no round log**)
- Added `-proc:only` option to javac command
- Also added `-processor org.immutables.processor.ProxyProcessor` to javac command (**processor now loaded**, but still no rounds printed and no classes generated)
- Changed the processor option to `-processor org.immutables.processor.ProxyProcessorXXX` to see if it would make a difference (**it did**, it now printed a warning stating that processing was requested with `proc:only`, but no processors were found)
- Checked to see if that warning appeared if I didn't use the `-processor` option, which should make javac detect processors from class path (**it didn't** show the warning, which suggests it's detecting processors yet the log doesn't show any sign of it)
- Tried above after switching from JDK1.8 to JDK9 (using jenv)
- Installed Zulu 1.7 and tried above after switching to it (using jenv)

### Possible factors

- I did an entirely clean install of macOS
- I ran macOS Sierra before, currently High Sierra
- Before I didn't have JDK9 installed
- I switched to using Gradle a long time ago, so I might have forgotten an important detail about maven

### Command options

This is the javac command I'm currently using:

`javac
 -d ./target/classes
 -classpath ./target/classes:$HOME/.m2/repository/com/google/dagger/dagger/2.4/dagger-2.4.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/2.4/dagger-compiler-2.4.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/com/google/auto/factory/auto-factory/1.0-beta3/auto-factory-1.0-beta3.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/org/immutables/builder/2.3.9/builder-2.3.9.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/org/immutables/value/2.3.9/value-2.3.9.jar:<LONG LIST OF DIRECT AND TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCIES HERE>
 -sourcepath ./src/main/java:
 -s ./target/generated-sources/annotations
 -verbose
 -XprintRounds
 -XprintProcessorInfo
 -Xlint
 -J-verbose 
 -processor org.immutables.processor.ProxyProcessor
 -proc:only 
 ./src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/Main.java`

*NOTE*: for better readability, I put each argument on a new line, replaced absolute paths with `$HOME/` and `./` and I omitted most dependencies.

### Question

What am I missing here? Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/386?

Comment: Thanks, that looked promising. I didn't consider the issue might be with immutables, but unfortunately I don't see any such errors in the log. Also tried another version of immutables but that didn't make a difference. It seems processing doesn't happen at all.

Comment: Actually, @yegodm, the issue you referenced does seem to be related; Although no such errors are printed, when I try to compile one specific class that has immutables annotations it works as expected. Strange that all annotation processors are no longer running though. I'll investigate further.

Comment: One thing that issue thread mentioned is to add  `-Xmaxerrs 100000` (I also added `-Xmaxwarns 100000`), or javac might not print the most relevant information because it's past the default error/warning limit. I tried that with Maven too, but unfortunately it has trouble handling these flags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3358578

Comment: What if you create a new bare maven project with just a few classes using same annotations and check if that compiles as you want it?

Answer (score 3):

`javac` appears to completely and silently skip annotation processing for some parse failures.

For me a duplicated annotation caused by a merge mistake caused thousands of failures because my annotation processors didn't run - so the real error got completely lost.

```
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
```

Comment: I can confirm this. In my case, the reason for a failure was also in another place (not related to annotion processors) after I merged lots of new changes.

Comment: All annotation processing seems to be skipped if you have `class B implements ClassA` (I was changing an interface to a class, missed one and got thousands of errors due to the annotation processing, making it impossible to find the error )

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember maven generates a marker file or marker directory (starting with a dot) for generated sources. But it's also a long time ago...

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue on a git branch, while the main branch built fine. The root cause turned out to be a .java source with a duplicate definition of a private void function. This duplicate was caused by a merge from the main branch. At first we did not notice it, because the merge did not cause conflicts. The problem occurred with Amazon Corretto 8 and 11 compilers.
After removing the duplicate private void function, the java compiler started generating sources as before.